# Neo4j- how to use WITH clause using c# client cypher

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I am trying to get the results using WITH clause in C# neo4j client.
Since I am new to neo4j, I do not have any idea on how to get the results in C#. 
Please help me with your suggestions

```
MATCH (cs:CrawlerInfo)
WITH cs, SIZE((cs)-[:CONTAINS]->()) as TotalResult
RETURN 
cs.CrawlerName,cs.Keyword,cs.SearchType,toint(TotalResult),cs.CrawlerInfoDate
order by toint(cs.CrawlerId) desc
```

Comment: Are you using `Neo4jClient` or `Neo4j-Driver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Neo4jClient` straight translation is the key, and should be discoverable via the API.

```
//gc = GraphClient instance
//CrawlerInfo is a class
gc.Cypher
    .Match("(cs:CrawlerInfo)")
    .With("cs, SIZE( (cs)-[:CONTAINS]->() ) as TotalResult")
    .Return((cs, TotalResult) => new
    {
        CrawlerName = cs.As<CrawlerInfo>().CrawlerName,
        Keyword = cs.As<CrawlerInfo>().Keyword,
        SearchType = cs.As<CrawlerInfo>().SearchType,
        CrawlerInfoDate = cs.As<CrawlerInfo>().CrawlerInfoDate,
        Size = Return.As<int>("toint(TotalResult)")
    })
    .OrderByDescending("toint(cs.CrawlerId)");
```

Personally, I would make my `CrawlerInfo` class look something like:

```
public class CrawlerInfo
{
    public int CrawlerId { get; set;}
    public string CrawlerName { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public string SearchType { get; set; }
    public string CrawlerInfoDate { get; set;}
}
```

Then you also don't/(shouldn't!) need to do the `toint`, which means you can do:

```
gc.Cypher
    .Match("(cs:CrawlerInfo)")
    .With("cs, SIZE( (cs)-[:CONTAINS]->() ) as TotalResult")
    .Return((cs, TotalResult) => new
    {
        CrawlerName = cs.As<CrawlerInfo>().CrawlerName,
        Keyword = cs.As<CrawlerInfo>().Keyword,
        SearchType = cs.As<CrawlerInfo>().SearchType,
        CrawlerInfoDate = cs.As<CrawlerInfo>().CrawlerInfoDate,
        Size = Return.As<int>("TotalResult")
    })
    .OrderByDescending("cs.CrawlerId");
```

Which is a bit tidier. I'd also be tempted to just return the `CrawlerInfo` object itself, rather than the properties (or make a small `CrawlerInfoLite` model if `CrawlerInfo` is massive):

```
gc.Cypher
    .Match("(cs:CrawlerInfo)")
    .With("cs, SIZE((cs)-[:CONTAINS]->()) as TotalResult")
    .Return((cs, TotalResult) => new
    {
        CrawlerInfo = cs.As<CrawlerInfo>(),
        Size = Return.As<int>("TotalResult")
    })
    .OrderByDescending("cs.CrawlerId");
```

Where `CrawlerInfo` is defined as:

```
public class CrawlerInfo
{
    public int CrawlerId { get; set;}
    public string CrawlerName { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public string SearchType { get; set; }
    public string CrawlerInfoDate { get; set;}
}
```